# Create PostgreSQL dump with ONE INSERT statement instead of INSERT per row

Tags: postgresql, backup, insert-into, pg-dump

I try to do a table data dump using pg_dump, something like this:

```
pg96\bin\pg_dump ... --format plain --section data --column-inserts --file obj.account.backup --table obj.account database_xyz
```

Instead of getting

```
INSERT INTO obj.account(name, email, password) VALUES ('user1','email1','password1');
INSERT INTO obj.account(name, email, password) VALUES ('user2','email2','password2');
```

I would like to get

```
INSERT INTO obj.account (name, email, password) VALUES 
('user1','email1','password1'),
('user2','email2','password2');
```

Is there a way for this without any Non-PostgreSQL postprocessing?

Comment: using `COPY` is not an option?..

Comment: No, so far I know, with copy I get a csv or tsv file. It's not what I want. Sure I could edit it afterwards, but that's what I would like to avoid.

Comment: COPY has binary format, and you can re-load the data directly into the table (also using COPY). No need for post processing. See `COPY TO` and `COPY FROM`.

Comment: Right, but this format is not useful if you would like to edit this data frequently in a text oriented programming IDE, especially if you have more then 10 columns. I'm not looking for workarounds .. if it is not possible no problem, then I know enough workarounds. The question was simply: is it possible or not? If NOT, it's ok.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to get `INSERT` statements like that with `pg_dump`.

Answer (score 3):

Since PostgreSQL 12 you can use pg_dump with **--rows-per-insert**=*nrows*, see https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/app-pgdump.html

I'm aware that this is an old question but I wanted to mention it in case somebody else (like me) finds this while searching for a solution. There are cases where COPY can't be used and for bigger data sets using a single INSERT statement is much faster when importing.